# Eclipse - Java - Auto Commenting (Alt-Shift-J) just adds blank comments

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, comments, autocommenting

I am trying to add comments to my code.  When I highlight a function and press Alt-Shift-J, it just adds three blank lines of commenting:

```
/**      
 *   
 */     
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("In Gateway doGet...");
        this.doRequest("GET", request, response);   }
```

NOTE - this is a screenshot of what my preferences looks like:
[image]

The "${tags} do nothing, but I put in a string for "Title" and it still does nothing. Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are extending `HttpServletRequest` since your `doGet` method is defined there and you are therefore overriding that method.

Since you are overriding a method, you need to select `Overriding methods` in that menu and then enter your comment:

[image]

With that, Eclipse will fill in the comment.

Comment: YES!  Thank you so much.  Such a simple response, but such a difficult answer for me to find.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sometimes the most obvious things are what we struggle to find most.